# Why isn't ODBCConnection.State reliable?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

Consider a simple setup:

```
// _conn is the OdbcConnection with a MySQL-Server (MySQL-Connector 3.51)
// _cmd is a created OdbcCommand

// Constructor has created the objects successfully

public void DoSomething() {
    if(_conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Now my problem is, that `OdbcConnection.State` isn't reliable. The thing is that after some time the connection gets lost, but the `State`-Property doesn't know anything about it and keeps telling me that the connection is open at least till the point were I try to execute a command (which fails gracefully). I even had the situation were the `State`-Property would never refresh and kept telling me that the connection was still there (but commands failed).

Of course I could add `Try {...} Catch {...}` blocks to my code, but I tried to avoid them because extending a two-line function with at least four lines of error handling is a little bit...heavy.

So my question is: Why isn't `OdbcConnection.State` reliable and can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nature of networking is that you often don't know there's a problem until you actually try to send data. If you simply pull the plug out of the back of the computer (or you pull the plug out of a switch somewhere in between your client and the server) then there's no way for the operating system to know until it actually tries to send data that there's even a problem.

The reason, then, that `State` is not reliable is because it's impossible to *make* it completely reliable without actually *actually trying to send data to the server*. Since that's far too much work for a simple property to do (a whole network roundtrip) it doesn't do that, and just does the simplest thing possible.

Also, there's the fact that there's a race condition between when you call `State == Open` and actually executing the command: you might call `State == Open`, and then someone pulls the plug before you execute the command.

So at the end of the day, you're going to have to have that exception handler anyway. I would also suggest that you don't put the exception around every single call to the database. If you're doing a website, then have a page-level handler and leave it at that. There's really no point trying "handle" a database going down in any other way than by displaying an error message to the user anyway...

Comment: The race condition you're describing is an example of [TOCTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).